# How to add columns on a view extracted from the same table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

i have these tables:

**attendance_tbl**

```
id     | date         | 
-----------------------
1      | 2020-03-15   |
2      | 2020-03-16   |
```

**student_tbl**

```
id     | attendance_id | name    | remark   |
---------------------------------------------
1      | 1             | oliver  | P        |
2      | 1             | john    | P        |
3      | 2             | oliver  | P        |
4      | 2             | john    | L        |
```

`attendance_id` is foreign from *attendance_tbl*

I want to achieve something like this:

```
name   | 2020-03-15  | 2020-03-16    |
--------------------------------------
oliver | P           | P             |
john   | P           | L             |
```

i am getting all the results between two dates (starting and beginning) so the columns may add up if there are more dates between the range given by the user.

but i'am having a hard time pulling this through.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to solve the above problem.

```
select names,
       Max(case when attendence_date='2020-03-15' then remark else null end) as '2015-03-15',
       max(case when attendence_date='2020-03-16' then remark else null end )as '2015-03-16' 
from attendence a 
join student_attendence b 
on a.id=b.attendence_id
group by names;
```